# Attaching Events to an Empty Array with jQuery.on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-on

Another question where I get to murder barry.

Can you attach events to an empty array using jQuery's `.on()` ?

```
var barry = new Person();
var steve = new Person();
var paul = new Person();

var people = [];


function Person() {

}

Person.prototype.murder = function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler("murder");
}


/*
    If I apply .on to an empty array the event is never triggered why?
            $(people).on("murder", function(){
       console.log("call the police");
    })

 */

people.push(barry)
people.push(steve)
people.push(paul)

$(people).on("murder", function() {
    console.log("call the police");
})

barry.murder();​
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/ZYkQm/2/) suggesting you can't;  but why not?  I would of assumed that the array is the delegate object?

Comment: The object is not even aware that it is in an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not binding events to an array. Calling the `$` function on an array `[a,b,c]` is the same as `$(a).add(b).add(c)`. And `$([])` is the same as just `$()` (an empty jQuery object).

Answer (score 2):

You can, but jQuery doesn't magically synthesize triggering methods for you.

```
people.trigger("murder");
```

It's also not going to work to trigger events on values that happen to be in the array; there's no event bubbling from array element to the containing array. Event bubbling works in the DOM, not on JavaScript data structures.

*edit* — oh sorry I see now that you've created your own `.murder()` API.  Fine then, but you've still got the issue with event bubbling.

There's no firm relationship between an object and any array that happens to contain a reference to it.  You could extend your API so that your "Person" objects could know where to send the events.

*edit again* — oh well I feel dumb now - this really doesn't have anything to do with an array as an object. When you wrap a jQuery object around an array instance, that's interpreted by the library as a request to treat the *elements* of the array as the members of the jQuery object.  Thus, when you add the event handler, the array doesn't really have anything to do with it: you're adding the handler to the individual elements.

Comment: @Pointy sorry, I've just updated the fiddle I forgot to include jQuery.  It does work for me (in chrome)

Comment: @CrimsonChin in Firefox even with jQuery imported, there's nothing logged on the console.

Comment: It should work considering jQuery converts the array to a jQuery object of 3 elements, and calling  `.on` on the jQuery object will attach a handler to each element separately.

Comment: Hi Pointy, you're right it doesnt ouput to console in firefox but if you change it to an alert it does seem to work

Comment: @CrimsonChin ah I see what's going on; sorry everybody :-)